# Por qué no puedo visualizar la firma con primefaces?

Tags: java, primefaces, firma-digital

No puedo visualizar la firma recuperada de la base de datos, no logro entender cual es el problema, alguien podria ayudarme gracias

```
<p:signature style="width:550px;height:200px" value="#{clienteDocumentosCollector.nuevaSolicitud.FIRMA_DIGITAL}" 
                                                     id="firmadig" widgetVar="sig"  
                                                     guideline="true"  />
```

La firma se guarda correctamene en la base de datos

> {"LINES":[[[112.3,70.94],[111.3,70.94],[109.3,73.94],[106.3,83.94],[106.3,90.94],[105.3,101.94],[105.3,102.94],[108.3,108.94],[117.3,114.94],[125.3,116.94],[131.3,116.94],[137.3,116.94],[167.3,100.94],[179.3,90.94],[199.3,70.94],[210.3,51.94],[213.3,35.94],[214.3,31.94],[214.3,34.94],[214.3,38.94],[214.3,56.94],[214.3,78.94],[216.3,88.94],[225.3,109.94],[232.3,115.94],[243.3,118.94],[251.3,118.94],[271.3,114.94],[299.3,99.94],[310.3,91.94],[331.3,73.94],[344.3,61.94],[351.3,52.94],[352.3,52.94],[352.3,52.94],[352.3,57.94],[351.3,65.94],[351.3,68.94],[351.3,76.94],[351.3,85.94],[356.3,94.94],[359.3,98.94],[367.3,102.94],[374.3,105.94],[380.3,105.94],[385.3,104.94],[389.3,100.94],[392.3,97.94],[393.3,94.94],[394.3,94.94]]]}

cuando hago la consulta si se recuran lo valores

[image: cuando hago la conssulta no muestra la firma graficada]

cuando examino el objeto esta vacio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Código del backing bean?

Comment: Unicamenete hago la consulta a la base de datos   

`public void llamaModificarSol(int v) {

   if (nuevaSolicitudSelected != null) {
      nuevaSolicitud = new SolicitudCredito();
    nuevaSolicitud = dbhelper.datosSolicitud(nuevaSolicitudSelected); 
         try {
                this.val = v;
                this.setVal(v);
                context.getExternalContext().redirect("CRE_L002.xhtml?val=" + val);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } `

Comment: Vas a tener que añadir más información a la pregunta.